# VC++08 make MFC apps DPI aware without updating VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dpi-aware

I may not have the option to simply update to a more recent VC++ version as would be ideal - the project is big and the update could break a lot of things, plus my lead may tell me not to pursue this. I'm wondering if anybody knows of a means by which an MFC app written using VC++08 can check resolution during runtime?

Comment: Does [Setting the default DPI awareness for a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process) not work?

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thanks so much. I'm pretty sure that I've found a way to do what I wanted by updating the app's manifest file - provided the file isn't embedded in the final exe. I'm now trying to find a way to add a few lines to a manifest file while still embedding it in the exe.

Comment: *Sniffle* it's beautiful. Just had to put my additional manifest info into a new manifest and add it to additional manifests so the manifest tool can merge it and boom. I have the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) for providing the answer I needed. A full update is not needed. DPI awareness can be activated via the app's manifest file. The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process) they provided was invaluable. Should anybody else have this issue and is using vs2008, if you cannot find the manifest file in the same dir as your exe after building, chances are, vs2008 has embedded the manifest in the exe. You can change this by opening the project's properties, going to manifest tool->IO. If you want to keep the manifest embedded, you can put your additional manifest info in a separate manifest file and provide the tool with the path of this file. The manifest tool will merge your manifest files.